# leaflet.js - Questions about polyline

Tags: leaflet

I have some questions about leaflet's polyline and they are as follows

- Is there a way when instantiating the polyline (L.polyline) to dictate that it should not show by default on the map?  I know that I can use .addTo([map]) and .remove() but is there a way to specify as part of the options?
- What is the best practice to hide/show polylines that are used to indicate a path between markers (L.marker)?  I know that I can add the markers to a layer group (L.layerGroup).  I know that when creating the polyline, I can use the same lat/lng for each of the markers indicating the path.  I know that I can show/hide each one of those individually (using L.Control.Layers and passing in the layer groups in as overlay maps and using that control to show/hide the markers and then, again, using the addTo() and .remove() for the polylines) but what I'm hoping to get help with is to make it show that the polylines show/hide when the layer group is visible/not visible and also show/hide them using an external control.  For the former case, I've tried using feature groups (L.featureGroup) but I could not get it to work.  For that latter case am I limited to .addTo() and .remove()?

thnx,
Christoph

Comment: That's a fairly lengthy question but to answer your first question, there isn't a direct way to do what you want with a polygon, however I would recommend just using a layergroup instead and just show and hide your polygon(s) that way. That may be a cleaner solution, at least that's what I've done in the past.

Comment: fixatd, thanks for the tip.  I was able to get the polyline added to the layer of markers so that they show/hide when that layer is made visible/not visible (when specified as an overly using L.Control.Layers).  I guess that went a fair ways to answering my second question.  I guess there isn't much I can do about my first question since you said there's no way to do it directly.  I guess I'm just going to have to use addTo() and remove() to do it manually.  I was hoping there was an easier way.  I'm instantiating these iteratively so I guess I'll need to somehow keep them in a group.